# How to play recording audio file in musicplayer in android?

Tags: android, audio-recording, android-music-player

In activity contains three buttons Button-1,Button-2,Button-3.

When i click on Button-1: It will records the audio and click on Button-2 it stop the recording and when click on Button-3 it will play audio it's working fine.

But i want to play that audio through music player.How to play the audio in music player.

For recording and playing audio i am creating this::

AudioRecord.Java

```
  public class AudioRecord {

private static MediaRecorder mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
public MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();;

private static String audioFilePath  = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
        .getAbsolutePath() + "/myaudio.3gp";
//Button recordButton, stopButton, playButton;

boolean isRecording = false;



public void recordAudio(final Button record,final Button stop,final Button play) throws IOException{

    record.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                isRecording = true;
                stop.setEnabled(true);
                play.setEnabled(false);
                record.setEnabled(false);

                try {
                    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
                    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
                    mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(audioFilePath);
                    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
                    mediaRecorder.prepare();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                mediaRecorder.start();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            stop.setEnabled(false);
            play.setEnabled(true);

            if (isRecording) {
                record.setEnabled(false);
                mediaRecorder.stop();
                mediaRecorder.release();
                mediaRecorder = null;
                isRecording = false;
            } else {
                mediaPlayer.release();
                mediaPlayer = null;
                record.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }
    });

    play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                play.setEnabled(false);
                record.setEnabled(false);
                stop.setEnabled(true);

                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                int i = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                System.out.println("Audio size"+" "+i);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioFilePath);
                mediaPlayer.prepare();
                mediaPlayer.start();

                mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        System.out.println("Audio cpmpleted ..............");
                        stop.setEnabled(false);
                        play.setEnabled(true);
                        record.setEnabled(true);
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        mediaPlayer = null;
                        //Toast.makeText(AudioRecord.this, "Audio Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });


}  
 }
```

I am using recordAudio() in side of my activity class.It's working fine.But i want to play audio in musicplayer when click on play button.And i want to return into Activity class when completing audio.

Any one plese help me.

Comment: Why are you making your own Media Player? Why not just open an existing , installed Music app from the device?. When user presses back from there, he'll go back to your app.

Comment: Yes,Sanjeev your correct.But,i want to go back into application when complete music with out user intraction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understood your problem now. I'm assuming your media player implementation is working fine, and you just to call back your original activity after music has finished.

You can use the [Completion Listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html) of Media Player class to do this.

```
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {

                Log.i("Completion Listener","Song Complete");

                /* Put your code to call back your activity here */
            }
        });
```

You can call back your original activity by variety of methods like `startActivity(intent)`. Basically, on completion of audio track, your listener will be called, then you can decide what to do. You can just print a message or you can call any activity you wish.

Here's the complete [**DEMO**](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/05/play-audio-using-mediaplayer.html)

Comment: The above answer working for me like chamm.But here i want to go back to my application when completing music.

Comment: When the music ends, it should automatically go back to your app?

Comment: No,It's not go back into my app.It show's me until i am click on back button.

Comment: @user2931067 Understood your problem. Answer updated. Use the `MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener`